# Is it possible to consider loops that cut through charges when proving electric field is conservative?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

[image: Electric field of a capacitor]

My goal is to prove that the integral of E.dl along the blue curve is zero. My problem is shouldn't E field approach a discontinuity when approaching the plate? Even if we consider say a point charge and try to evaluate the integral on a loop that goes around the world back to the same point wouldn't we encounter an undefined E field at the point where the charge exists? Or is it futile to consider such loops that cut through charges?

Answer (score 1):

If this is a time-independent problem, why would you worry? Faraday's law tells you that
$$\oint \vec{E}\cdot d\vec{l} = -\int \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\vec{B} \cdot d\vec{A},$$
so if there isn't any changing magnetic flux through the loop then the closed line integral is zero.

I'll add that yes, in an ideal capacitor there would be *two* discontinuities as you entered and exited the plate on each of its surfaces. If you were trying to do the line integral, all you would need to do is split the integral at the discontinuities.

Comment: I am not worried about proving the integral as much as I am about handling that discontinuity. Are you saying that I simply disregard that point where the plate exists on the loop?

Comment: @eoshah How big is the electric field *inside* the plate?

Comment: If I consider the plate to be infinitesimally thin(the plate is an ideal one layered plane of charges) then I'm afraid I don't know the answer because electric field inside charges have no meaning. And that's exactly why I raised this question. What if the source of the E field falls inside the loop I'm evaluating the integral on?